# return values of components in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Yii framework:)
Suppose that we have two files, one controller:

```
    Yii::app()->egopay->testf('testtext_testtext_testtext');
echo $test;
```

and second component:

```
public function testf($t){
    $test = $t;
return $test;
}
```

I have a very long code whose value does not copy the but works on the same principle, therefore, must be paying a variable from the component to the controller.
Why can not I display the returned value component?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Which is the controller, model, view?  Are you passing payment information to a gateway?

Comment: There are examples of using other payment gateway APIs like braintree: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=payment+system

Answer (score 0):

I would first see if braintree could be used instead of egopay.  But that is not always the choice of the developer...  Then use the braintree extension inside of protected/extensions/BraintreeApi/

If not then use the Egopay SCI package and put it inside say:

```
protected/extensions/EgopayApi/
```

Then in the Controller for Payments? Cart? make a new action for the payment link:

```
public function actionPayment() {
  $model = ; # maybe find by primary key for user?
  # example: $model = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
  Yii::import('ext.EgoPaySci.models.EgopayCCForm');  # Brings in the EgoPaySci.php and form if any
  $payment = new EgopayCCForm(array('store_id' => 8888, 'store_password' => 'JkkYhs7ft'));
```

The values from EgoPaySci.php will be available via: $payment

Sorry for being vague but I am assuming you are doing a payment gateway.  And there is a lot of details to explain.  But setting this up in the Controller will make it available to the model and therefor the views also.

Answer (score 0):

not quite what I meant. And here is ready to like someone needed a :)

```
controller:
$test = Yii::app()->egopay->testf('testtext_testtext_testtext');
echo 'variable a:'.$test['a'];
echo $test['b'];
echo $test['c'];

components:
public function testf($t){
    $var['a'] = $t;
    $var['b'] = 'variable b: '.$t;
    $var['c'] = 'variable c: '.$t;
return $var;
}
```

but anyway thanks for the reply :)